# How to manually apply matrix stack to coordinates in processing

Tags: processing

In processing, when you apply a matrix transformation, you can draw on your canvas without worrying of the "true" position of your x y coordinate.

I thought that by the same logic, I could copy a section of the canvas by using ParentApplet.get(x, y, width, height) and that it would automatically shift the x and y, but it does not, it uses the coordinates as raw inputs without applying the matrix stack to it.

So the easiest way I see to deal with the problem would be to manually apply the matrix stack to my x, y, width, height values and using the results as input of get(). But I cannot find such a function, does one exist ?

**EDIT** : As requested, Here's an example of my problem

So the objective here is to draw a simple shape, copy it and paste it. Without translate, there is no problem:

```
void settings(){
    size(500, 500);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  
  // Fancy rectangle for visibility
  fill(255, 0 ,0);
  rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
  fill(0, 255, 0);
  rect(20, 20, 60, 60);
  
  // copy rectangle and paste it elsewhere
  PImage img = get(0, 0, 101, 101);
  image(img, 200, 200);
}
```

[image]

Now if I applied a translate matrix before drawing the shape, I wish that I could use the same get() code to copy the exact same drawing:

```
void settings(){
    size(500, 500);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  pushMatrix();
  translate(10, 10);
  
  // Fancy rectangle for visibility
  fill(255, 0 ,0);
  rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
  fill(0, 255, 0);
  rect(20, 20, 60, 60);
  
  // copy rectangle and paste it elsewhere
  PImage img = get(0, 0, 101, 101);
  image(img, 200, 200);
  
  popMatrix();
}
```

But it doesn't work that way, The get(0, 0, ..) doesn't use the current transformation matrix to copy pixels from origin (10, 10):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please provide a few more details.
It is possible to manipulate coordinate systems using [pushMatrix()/PopMatrix()](https://processing.org/tutorials/transform2d/) and you can go further and manually multiply matrices and vectors.

The part that is confusing is that you're calling `get(x,y,width,height)` but no showing how you render the `PImage` section. It's hard to guess the matrix stack you're mentioning. Can you post an example snippet ?

If you render it at the same x,y you call `get()` with it should render with the same x,y shift:

```
size(640, 360);
noFill();
strokeWeight(9);

PImage placeholderForPGraphics = loadImage("https://processing.org/examples/moonwalk.jpg");
image(placeholderForPGraphics, 0, 0);

int x = 420;
int y = 120;
int w = 32;
int h = 48;
// visualise region of interest
rect(x, y, w, h);

// grab the section sub PImage
PImage section = placeholderForPGraphics.get(x, y, w, h);

//filter the section to make it really standout
section.filter(THRESHOLD);
// display section at same location
image(section, x, y);
```

[image: render PImage subsection]

Regarding the matrix stack, you can call [`getMatrix()`](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PGraphics.html#getMatrix--) which will return a [PMatrix2D](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PMatrix2D.html) if you're in 2D mode (otherwise a [PMatrix3D](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PMatrix3D.html)). This is a copy of the current matrix stack at the state you've called it (any prior operations will be "baked" into this one).

For example:

```
PMatrix m = g.getMatrix();
printArray(m.get(new float[]{}));
```

(`g.printMatrix()` should be easier to print to console, but you need to call `getMatrix()` if you need an instance to manipulate)

Where `g` is your PGraphics instance.

You can then manipulate it as you like:

```
m.translate(10, 20);
m.rotate(radians(30));
m.scale(1.5);
```

Remember to call `applyMatrix()` it when you're done:

```
g.applyMatrix(m);
```

Trivial as it may be I hope this modified version of the above example illustrates the idea:

```
size(640, 360);
noFill();
strokeWeight(9);
// get the current transformation matrix
PMatrix m = g.getMatrix();
// print to console
println("before");
g.printMatrix();
// modify it
m.translate(160, 90);
m.scale(0.5);
// apply it
g.applyMatrix(m);
// print applied matrix
println("after");
g.printMatrix();


PImage placeholderForPGraphics = loadImage("https://processing.org/examples/moonwalk.jpg");
image(placeholderForPGraphics, 0, 0);

int x = 420;
int y = 120;
int w = 32;
int h = 48;
// visualise region of interest
rect(x, y, w, h);

// grab the section sub PImage
PImage section = placeholderForPGraphics.get(x, y, w, h);

//filter the section to make it really standout
section.filter(THRESHOLD);
// display section at same location
image(section, x, y);
```

Here's another example making a basic into `PGraphics` using matrix transformations:

```
void setup(){
  size(360, 360);
  
  // draw something manipulating the coordinate system
  PGraphics pg = createGraphics(360, 360);
  pg.beginDraw();
  pg.background(0);
  pg.noFill();
  pg.stroke(255, 128);
  pg.strokeWeight(4.5);
  pg.rectMode(CENTER);
  pg.translate(180,180);
  for(int i = 0 ; i < 72; i++){
    pg.rotate(radians(5));
    pg.scale(0.95);
    //pg.rect(0, 0, 320, 320, 32, 32, 32, 32);
    polygon(6, 180, pg);
  }
  pg.endDraw();
  
  // render PGraphics
  image(pg, 0, 0);
  
  }
```

[image: concentric hexagons]

This is overkill: the same effect could have been drawn much simpler, however the focus in on calling `get()` and using transformation matrices. Here a modified iteration showing the same principle with `get(x,y,w,h)`, then `image(section,x,y)`:

```
void setup(){
  size(360, 360);
  
  // draw something manipulating the coordinate system
  PGraphics pg = createGraphics(360, 360);
  pg.beginDraw();
  pg.background(0);
  pg.noFill();
  pg.stroke(255, 128);
  pg.strokeWeight(4.5);
  pg.rectMode(CENTER);
  pg.translate(180,180);
  for(int i = 0 ; i < 72; i++){
    pg.rotate(radians(5));
    pg.scale(0.95);
    //pg.rect(0, 0, 320, 320, 32, 32, 32, 32);
    polygon(6, 180, pg);
  }
  pg.endDraw();
  
  // render PGraphics
  image(pg, 0, 0);

 
  // take a section of PGraphics instance
  int w = 180;
  int h = 180;
  int x = (pg.width - w) / 2;
  int y = (pg.height - h) / 2;
  PImage section = pg.get(x, y, w, h);
  
  // filter section to emphasise
  section.filter(INVERT);
  
  // render section at sampled location
  image(section, x, y);
  popMatrix();
  
}

void polygon(int sides, float radius, PGraphics pg){
  float angleIncrement = TWO_PI / sides;
  pg.beginShape();
  for(int i = 0 ; i <= sides; i++){
    float angle = (angleIncrement * i) + HALF_PI;
    pg.vertex(cos(angle) * radius, sin(angle) * radius);
  }
  pg.endShape();
}
```

[image: section rendered inverted]

Here's a final iteration re-applying the last transformation matrix in an isolated coordinate space (using push/pop matrix calls):

```
void setup(){
  size(360, 360);
  
  // draw something manipulating the coordinate system
  PGraphics pg = createGraphics(360, 360);
  pg.beginDraw();
  pg.background(0);
  pg.noFill();
  pg.stroke(255, 128);
  pg.strokeWeight(4.5);
  pg.rectMode(CENTER);
  pg.translate(180,180);
  for(int i = 0 ; i < 72; i++){
    pg.rotate(radians(5));
    pg.scale(0.95);
    //pg.rect(0, 0, 320, 320, 32, 32, 32, 32);
    polygon(6, 180, pg);
  }
  pg.endDraw();
  
  // render PGraphics
  image(pg, 0, 0);
  
  // take a section of PGraphics instance
  int w = 180;
  int h = 180;
  int x = (pg.width - w) / 2;
  int y = (pg.height - h) / 2;
  PImage section = pg.get(x, y, w, h);
  
  // filter section to emphasise
  section.filter(INVERT);
  
  // print last state of the transformation matrix
  pg.printMatrix();
  
  // get the last matrix state
  PMatrix m = pg.getMatrix();
  // isolate coordinate space
  pushMatrix();
  //apply last PGraphics matrix
  applyMatrix(m);
  // render section at sampled location
  image(section, x, y);
  popMatrix();
  
  save("state3.png");
}

void polygon(int sides, float radius, PGraphics pg){
  float angleIncrement = TWO_PI / sides;
  pg.beginShape();
  for(int i = 0 ; i <= sides; i++){
    float angle = (angleIncrement * i) + HALF_PI;
    pg.vertex(cos(angle) * radius, sin(angle) * radius);
  }
  pg.endShape();
}
```

[image: pmatrix applied]

This is an extreme example, as `0.95` downscale is applied 72 times, hence a very small image is rendered. Also notice the rotation is incremented.

**Update** Based on your update snippet it seems the confusion is around `pushMatrix()` and `get()`.

In your scenario, `pushMatrix()/translate()` will offset the local coordinate sytem: that is where elements are drawn.
`get()` is called globally and uses absolute coordinates.

If you're only using translation, you can simply store the translation coordinates and re-use them to sample from the same location:

```
int sampleX = 10;
int sampleY = 10;

void settings(){
    size(500, 500);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  pushMatrix();
  translate(sampleX, sampleY);
  
  // Fancy rectangle for visibility
  fill(255, 0 ,0);
  rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
  fill(0, 255, 0);
  rect(20, 20, 60, 60);
  
  // copy rectangle and paste it elsewhere
  PImage img = get(sampleX, sampleY, 101, 101);
  image(img, 200, 200);
  
  popMatrix();
}
```

**Update**
Here are a couple more examples on how to compute, rather than hard code the translation value:

```
void settings(){
    size(500, 500);
}

void setup() {
  background(255);
  pushMatrix();
  translate(10, 10);
  // Fancy rectangle for visibility
  fill(255, 0 ,0);
  rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
  fill(0, 255, 0);
  rect(20, 20, 60, 60);
  // local to global coordinate conversion using PMatrix
  // g is the global PGraphics instance every PApplet (sketch) uses
  PMatrix m = g.getMatrix();
  printArray(m.get(null));
  // the point in local coordinate system
  PVector local = new PVector(0,0);
  // multiply local point by transformation matrix to get global point
  // we pass in null to get a new PVector instance: you can make this more efficient by allocating a single PVector ad re-using it instead of this basic demo
  PVector global = m.mult(local,null);
  // copy rectangle and paste it elsewhere
  println("local",local,"->global",global);
  PImage img = get((int)global.x, (int)global.y, 101, 101);
  image(img, 200, 200);
  
  popMatrix();
}
```

To calculate the position of a vector based on a transformation matrix, simply multiply the vector by that matrix. Very roughly speaking what's what happens with push/pop matrix (a transformation matrix is used for each push/pop stack, which is then multiplied all the way up the global coordinate system). (Notice the comment on efficienty/pre-allocating matrices and vectors as well).

This will be more verbose in terms of code and may need a bit of planning if you're using a lot of nested transformations, however you have finer control of which transformations you choose to use.

A simpler solution may be to switch to the `P3D` OpenGL renderer which allows you use [`screenX()`](https://processing.org/reference/screenX_.html), [`screenY()`](https://processing.org/reference/screenY_.html) to do this conversion. (Also checkout `modelX()`/`modelY()`)

```
void settings(){
    size(500, 500, P3D);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  pushMatrix();
  translate(10, 10);
  // Fancy rectangle for visibility
  fill(255, 0 ,0);
  rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
  fill(0, 255, 0);
  rect(20, 20, 60, 60);
  // local to global coordinate conversion using modelX,modelY
  float x = screenX(0, 0, 0);
  float y = screenY(0, 0, 0);
  println(x,y);
  PImage img = get((int)x, (int)y, 101, 101);
  image(img, 200, 200);
  
  popMatrix();
}
```

Bare in mind that you want to grab a rectangle which simply has translation applied. Since `get()` won't take rotation/scale into account, for more complex cases you may want to convert local to global coordinates of not just the top left point, but also the bottom right one with an offset. The idea is to compute the larger bounding box (with no rotation) around the transformed box so when you call `get()` the whole area of interest is returned (not just a clipped section).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thank you for such a detailed answer. I updated my post with a short snippet of the problem. From my understanding it is different from your explanation as I'm trying to create a PImage by copying a certain area of the canvas, but I want this copy area to be translated by the transformation matrix.

Comment: @Pythalex much appreciated. Thank you for sharing the snippet: it's great at illustrating your goal. I've updated my answer above. Hopefully this addresses your question ?

Comment: As I feared, the get function doesn't use the transformation matrix like the draw functions. As I'm currently only using the translate transformation in my project, that's how I solved my problem. It seems that the PMatrix2D returned by getMatrix is the thing I was looking for in case I was using more complex transformations. Thank you !

Comment: Yup, you've got it! I've added a few more details for you above, including getMatrix(), but also `screenX()/screenY()` which may be simpler in some cases (if you're constraint to a specific renderer and can use `P3D`). A pleasure to help :)